# How to force an object to update react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a variable which is constructed based on a stateful variable, but isn't itself stored in state, and it's not re-rendering properly when the underlying data changes. Is there a way to force this object to completely rerender whenever the underlying state variable changes?

Edit: Unfortunately I can't post the whole code sample (and am sorry to ask the question without being able to see the whole context) but here's a bit more. `circles` is an array which the user can add to by tapping a button, and the array is then rendered to the screen based on another component. What I'm trying to do is to have each circle basically scale down in proportion to the number of circles in the array. This works partially in that the marginal circle is the scaled down size, but the earlier ones don't re-render. I was able to force a rerender in a really roundabout way which gave me the expected behavior, but it caused some other problems.

Here's some code for context (again this is not the whole thing, but I hope might help identify the problem.

```
render(): ReactElement {
var circles = this.state.keys.map((key, idx) => {
//code omitted
}

 return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <View style={[{flex: 1, overflow: 'hidden', margin: 5, marginTop: 20},  ]}>
          <View style={styles.left} onLayout={(e) => this.setState({layout: e.nativeEvent.layout})}>
                {circles}
                </View>}
              </View>
            </View>
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Is the member variable used anywhere in the ui?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Two ways, 1. by using this.setState, 2. by using this.forceUpdate()

Comment: Thanks for the comment, what trigger should I use for forceUpdate? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation is a cache approach. i.e. when your state changes, the variable circle will not re-calculate automatically.

so you may want to change the circle into a function:

```
var getCircles = function() {
    return this.state.keys.map((key, idx) => {
       // ....
    })
}
```

then use getCircles() in your render()

Answer (score 1):

A react component always re-renders on a state or props update unless you explicitly tell it not to in shouldComponentUpdate(). Without having seen the code I suppose that you don't calculate the derived variable in the render method. In this case you have to options:

1. Move the calculation of the derived variable into render()
2. Use the componentWillUpdate() or componentWillReceiveProps() methods to recalculate when something changes.